# How can I add a Hinglish font in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a English name but font type similar to hindi. its font is available in samarkan.
https://www.fontspace.com/category/hinglish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Hinglish Nikolevna Regular from the linked site to sample:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Hinglish';
  src: url('HinglishNikolevnaRegular-Vp5B.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
   font-family: 'Hinglish', sans-serif;
}
```